# How to make list in a query with only a certain character

Tags: sql-server

Below is a table that I am working with:

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME FIRST_3_CHARACTERS NUMBER
Bill        Whithers FIRST_3_CHARACTERS LAST_3_CHARACTERS NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_FIRST_NAME CHARACTER234
John        Lennon
Jack        White
John        Coltrane
```

Everything that doesn't have a value are null. What the column names are, are exactly what they say. I need to take the first three characters of their full name, the last three characters of their full name, the number of characters in their first name, and character234, meaning character 2, character 3 and character 4. So for example if we looked at John Lennon, it would be joh, non, 4, ohn. I am fairly new to sequel and I am unsure how to make values and put them into a null row. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? This seems a lot like homework to me. You need to look at the string manipulation functions in sql server. Mostly, Left, right and substring. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Comment: Already answered. Just a few short comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `LEN` and `SUBSTRING` functions:

```
select left(first_name, 3) as FIRST_3_CHARACTERS, 
       right(last_name, 3) as LAST_3_CHARACTERS, 
       len(first_name) as NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_FIRST_NAME, 
       substring(first_name, 2, 3) as CHARACTER234
from TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. I've added demo data.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(firstname nvarchar(50), lastname nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #temp(firstname,lastname)
VALUES(N'John', N'Lennon')

-- This do the trick
SELECT LEFT(firstname,3), RIGHT(lastname,3), LEN(firstname), SUBSTRING(firstname,2,3)
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Do you need more comments on the statement itself?